# JPA map Database to Enum

Tags: java, jpa

I have a database table which has a few rows:

`table Cars`

```
+  id   +     name      +
+-------+---------------+
+  1    |  AUDI         |
+  2    |  BMW          |
+  3    |  MERCEDES     |
+-------+---------------+
```

In my Java Code I want to use the table as an `enum` like this:
`entity.setModel(Cars.BMW)`

My question is if it is possible in JPA to map a Table to an `enum`

Thanks

Comment: why would you do that? In Java code you have a fixed enum class (with ordinal + name), and then somebody frigs about with your CARS table in the datastore and they are suddenly inconsistent! Just don't

Answer (score 0):

No because an enum cannot be an entity.

It wouldn't make sense because an Java enum is not changeable but your table Cars is.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use it like a field of some entity, you can declare it like this:

```
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "cars", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "your_entity_id"))
    @Column(name = "car")
    private Cars car;
```